# Sum of first n natural numbers using promises?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, callback, es6-promise

So the problem is I have to get the sum of first `n` natural  numbers but the conditions are

1.Using a helper function which returns a `promise`

2.Cannot use `+` operator inside the main function (only allowed in the in the helper function).

3.Cannot use `async` - `await`

The *so-far* solution I came to is

```
nat_sum =  (n) =>{
let i=1,res=0;

while(i<=n){
    sumP(res,i++).then( data => {
        res = data;
        console.log(res);
    }); 
    console.log("res is ",i, res);
} 

};
```

```
//Helper function is

function sumP(x,y){
    // Always resolves 
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        resolve(x+y);
    });
}
```

But the problem is, the loop just initializes all the call to the `sumP` with initial value of `res` i.e `0` , which means it just doesn't wait for the former promise to `resolve` and update the `res` variable.

Same problem solved using a callback is as follows (You can ignore this, *Just a insight to the problem*!) :

```
function sumc(x,y,callme){
    return callme(x,y);
}
```

```
nat_sumC = (n)=>{
  let i=1,res=0;
  while(i<=n){
        res = sumc(res,i++,sum);
    }
  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `recursion`

```js
function sumP(x, y) {  //Helper function
  // Always resolves
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(x + y);
  });
}

const naturalSum = (n, i = 1, res = 0) => {
  sumP(res, i).then(data => {
    if (i == n) {
      console.log(data);
      return;
    }
    naturalSum(n, ++i, data)
  });
};

naturalSum(5)
naturalSum(6)
```

Comment: `naturalSum` should return a promise so you can get the value, ie `naturalSum(5).then(console.log)` would print `15`. You can fix this by adding a `return` before `sumP(res,i)...` and change `.then(...)` to `.then(data => { if (i === n) return data; else return naturalSum(n, i + 1, data) })`

Comment: @user633183 seems nice. but op didn't mention `naturalSum` should return a `promise`

Answer (score 0):

You should use recursion:

```js
const nat_sum = n => {
  let i = 0;
  let recurse = res =>
    sumP(res)
      .then(recurse)
      .catch(e => console.info(`Sum of numbers 1 to ${n} is ${e}`));

  function sumP(x) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (i < n) {
        resolve(x + ++i);
      } else reject(x);
    });
  }
  recurse(0); //Recurse from 0
};

[4, 5, 6, 15].forEach(nat_sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the `answer` to the smaller problem, `n - 1`, `then` add `n` to `answer` using `sumP` -

```js
function natSum(n){
  if (n === 0)
    return Promise.resolve(0)
  else
    return natSum(n - 1).then(answer => sumP(n, answer))
}

// provided helper function
function sumP(x,y){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        resolve(x+y);
    });
}

natSum(4).then(console.log) // 10
natSum(5).then(console.log) // 15
natSum(6).then(console.log) // 21
```

Rewriting with arrows, we can remove a lot of syntactic noise -

```js
const sumP = (x, y) =>
  Promise .resolve (x + y)

const natSum = n =>
  n === 0
    ? Promise .resolve (0)
    : natSum (n - 1) .then (r => sumP (n, r))

natSum (4) .then (console.log) // 10
natSum (5) .then (console.log) // 15
natSum (6) .then (console.log) // 21
```

Using `async` and `await` only hides the Promise primitives like `Promise.resolve` and `.then` -

```js
const sumP = async (x, y) =>
  x + y //<-- returns promise because of "async" keyword

const natSum = async n =>
  n === 0
    ? 0
    : sumP (n, (await natSum (n - 1)))

natSum (4) .then (console.log) // 10
natSum (5) .then (console.log) // 15
natSum (6) .then (console.log) // 21
```